# Highstock - navigator zoom button issue after remove/add series

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highstock stacked column chart to display data. There is implemented the drilldown functionality - i.e. after click to the particular column, in the background there are removed the existing series (except 'navigator') and added the new series with particular data. After remove previous series and add a new series the navigator ALL button doesn't show really all data but data for 6m or 1y. In my opinion there is missing some synchronizing process between the displayed data and navigator. Is there any way to correct it?
I am using the next settings:

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime'
},
navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    adaptToUpdatedData: true,
    series : {
        id: 'navigator'
    }
},
series: {
    events: {
        click: function (e) {
            var series = ObtainNewData();
            setChart(e, chart, series);
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
setChart: function(e, chart, series){
    var navigatorSerie;
    var chartSeriesLength = chart.series.length;
    for(var i = chartSeriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--){
        if(chart.series[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'navigator') {
            navigatorSerie = chart.series[i]; 
        } else {
            chart.series[i].remove(false);
        }
    }
    $.each(series, function(i, n ){
        chart.addSeries(n, false);
        navigatorSerie.setData(n.data, false);
    });
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes();
    chart.redraw();
},
```

before the previous version of the code I tried to use more easily way without 'navigator' serie where I used:

```
setChart: function(e, chart, series){
    var chartSeriesLength = chart.series.length;
    for(var i = chartSeriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--){
        chart.series[i].remove(false);
    }
    $.each(series, function(i, n ){
        chart.addSeries(n, false);
    });
    chart.redraw();
},
```

Comment: How about using `drilldown` module? See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8sy0nse4/

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible in my case, because for obtain the top level data I am using the different service request than for the drilldown level. After click to the column on the top level, in the background there is the request to obtain drilldown level data.

Comment: We found out, that the real problem of our issue regarding navigator zoom buttons was on our side (wrong service parameters).